# what is the meaning of this statement in JavaScript: var no=eval('"'+id+'"');

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of the following code in JavaScript:

```
var no=eval('"'+id+'"');
```

I want to know: What is `id`? Is it a variable or string?

Comment: as a rough guess - it is converting a variable value to a string. It would be easier to use var no = "" + id; Without the context of what id actually is makes it difficult to say what is happening with any great accuracy

Comment: `id` is expected by this to be a variable. Its value is given double-quotes as a prefix and suffix, then the combined string value is evaluated as though it were code. It is seemingly trying to prepare the value of `id` as a string literal for `eval()` to parse. (Though, `var no = String(id);` would have the same result and wouldn't risk invoking code you didn't intend to.)

Comment: The meaning is that the programmer did not know what he or she was doing.

Answer (score 1):

eval() is a function property of the global object.

The argument of the eval() function is a string. If the string represents an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument represents one or more JavaScript statements, eval() evaluates the statements. Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically.

If you construct an arithmetic expression as a string, you can use eval() to evaluate it at a later time. For example, suppose you have a variable x. You can postpone evaluation of an expression involving x by assigning the string value of the expression, say "3 * x + 2", to a variable, and then calling eval() at a later point in your script.

If the argument of eval() is not a string, eval() returns the argument unchanged. In the following example, the String constructor is specified, and eval() returns a String object rather than evaluating the string.
[more details click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Do not construct an arithmetic expression as a string.